# read non-formatted column value

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, unix

I am trying to read all values for `"Description 4"` column. I can read it if all values are in same line and none of the values are empty but in below case some are empty values and some values are not oriented in same line as others. Please suggest how can i just pull all values below "`description 4`".

Below entire italic text with columns in between is from where i need to fetch `Description 4`

*A.  warrants and represents to  that  has full legal title to the  listed below and/or mobile  in which the  is contained , free and clear of all liens and esffcswes and cdwswys such title, and any regqsdfon and  documents (as
   applicable), to effective as of the date of the removal or of the (as applicable).*

```
                                                                                                           Description
   Description 1.          Description 2              Description 3            Description 4
                                                                                                          Amount ($)

                                                                               LSMSNDHAM107            25,000
   Variable length value             DCX12300                     1
                                                                                XWSAQ23A1CM
   VariableLengthValue                                        1                                               4,000
```

*B. In cases where will be removing the  will, at its expense, arrange for removal of the  during  normal business hours or on aschedule.
    and so on document will continue.*

Comment: try using an ASCI table generator (like [this](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)) to show us what you mean, because it's hard to understand what you just pasted in the question

Comment: If you are not actually writing Python code at all at this point, restricting to Python 2.x (with the [tag:python-2.7] tag) seems extremely misdirected.  There are reasons Python 2 is still being kept alive for a couple of years, but it's certainly not to encourage new programs to be written in Python 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer for original version of question

From your sample input, it appears that the values that you want are in columns 80 to 95 of your file.  If that is the case, then use `cut`:

```
$ cut -b80-95 File

Description 4


LSMSNDHAM107    

 XWSAQ23A1CM
```

If you don't want the empty lines, we can use:

```
$ cut -b80-95 File | grep '[^[:space:]]'
Description 4
LSMSNDHAM107    
 XWSAQ23A1CM
```

#### Answer for revised question

In the revised question, there are paragraphs of text before and after the table like this:

```
$ cat file2
A.  warrants and represents to  that  has full legal title to the  listed below and/or mobile  in which the  is contained , free and clear of all liens and esffcswes and cdwswys such title, and any regqsdfon and  documents (as
   applicable), to effective as of the date of the removal or of the (as applicable).

                                                                                                               Description
       Description 1.          Description 2              Description 3            Description 4
                                                                                                              Amount ($)

                                                                                   LSMSNDHAM107            25,000
       Variable length value             DCX12300                     1
                                                                                    XWSAQ23A1CM
       VariableLengthValue                                        1                                               4,000


B. In cases where will be removing the  will, at its expense, arrange for removal of the  during  normal business hours or on aschedule.
```

We can select column 4 from the table that exists between the paragraphs as follows:

```
$ awk 'f && /^[[:alnum:]]/{exit} f{s=substr($0, 80, 15)} f && s~/[[:alnum:]]/{print s} /Description 4/{f=1}' file2
    LSMSNDHAM10
     XWSAQ23A1C
```

**How it works:**

The code uses a variable `f` as a flag: it is one (true) when we are in the range of lines which we want to print and zero (false) elsewhere.

- `f && /^[[:alnum:]]/{exit}`

  If `f` is true and the current line starts with an alphanumeric character, then we have reached the end of the table and we `exit` the program.
- `f{s=substr($0, 80, 15)}`

  If `f` is true, then we save characters 80 through 95 of the current line in variable `s`.
- `f && s~/[[:alnum:]]/{print s}`

  If f is true and the variable `s` contains any alphanumeric characters, then we print s.
- `/Description 4/{f=1}`

  If the current line matches the regex `Description 4`, then we set `f` to one.

It is important to keep these commands in this order.

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry i didn't gave complete text at first place, i have updated it now. We have paragraphs before and after.

Comment: Then maybe `sed -n '1,/Description 4/d;/^ /q;/[^ ]/p' file | cut -b80-95` to first extract the section you want.

Comment: @John1024 can you please explain it because this is working for majority of file but for few i am getting text from passage below the table.

Comment: @ankitpandey I just added an explanation.  If you are getting lines from after the table, then the problem is likely with the test `/^[[:alnum:]]/`.  This test assumes that any line whose first character is alphanumeric (not blank), marks the end of the table.  Depending on what the problem files look like, you might need a different test.